# Convert array of strings into an array of hashes in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON returned from the server:

```
tags = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
[{"text":"tag1"},{"text":"tag2"},{"text":"tag3"}]
```

I get close by running this code:

```
var new_list = []
for (i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
  new_list.push({'text' : tags[i]});
}
new_list = JSON.stringify(new_list, ['text']);
```

which returns:

```
 '[{"text":"tag1"},{"text":"tag2"},{"text":"tag3"}]'
```

but I can't get rid of the string encapsulating the whole array and I feel there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: If you want an array as result, why do you serialize it in the end? Remove the `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: There is not need to do `JSON.stringify(new_list, ['text']);`

Comment: If I don't stringify, the "text" key is not a string. I get [ { text: 'work' }, { text: 'this' }, { text: 'does' } ]

Comment: @Finnjon Keys in plain JS objects are _always_ strings. Only exception is the new `Symbol()`, which you do not use here.

Comment: @Finnjon All keys are strings (OK, except for arrays, which can have numbers).

Comment: @Sirko Oh I see. The quotes get stripped out in the editor so I was confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is producing the output what you are expecting

just because you are using JSON.strigify() it is converting it into string

You are saying that without stringify your key value are not displaying as string.

For your information By default **all the keys are STRING** in JSON

So nothing wrong in it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your JSON.stringify().

That function take a JSON object and trasform it into a string.

You can use nothing or, if you need JSON, try

JSON.parse()

reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON